# My windows machine has no password, why does WSL ask for one when sudoing?

Tags: windows-10, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My windows machine has no password, and I don't remember setting one for WSL.

When I try to use `sudo`, I get asked for a password. Because of the above I don't know what the password is.

Why is it asking me for a password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's asking for a password because you are invoking sudo.
sudo doesn't know what the password is, it just compares a hash. Because it has a hash to nothing, no answer can be the correct one.

You need to add an admin password.

Comment: WSL distros ask for the user’s password upon creation.  This password has nothing to do with the user’s Windows password and is completely separate.

Comment: @GregW I must have forgotten that